# Android studio crashed every time

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ubuntu-16.04

Every time I tried to start the android studio it crashed with following message .

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f7638f2cc5f, pid=15720, tid=0x00007f76381f9700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_76-b03) (build 1.8.0_76-release-b03)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.76-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x821c5f]  void ParScanClosure::do_oop_work<unsigned int>(unsigned int*, bool, bool) [clone .constprop.309]+0xdf
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/mithun/java_error_in_STUDIO_15720.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
Aborted (core dumped)



My OS: ubuntu 16.04
Android studio version : 2.2 (tried with 2.3 too same error)
```

Tried changing java version from java 7 to openjdk 8

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982396/failed-to-write-core-dump-core-dumps-have-been-disabled

Comment: Hi! I'm on Ubuntu 16.10, Android Studio 2.3 and my Java version is OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-8u111-b14-2ubuntu0.16.10.2-b14). All is working flawlessly here. Is it a big problem for you to upgrade to latest Ubuntu version? To be fair, never had this problem on 16.04, so there's something really broken on your Java JRE enviroment.

Comment: @MartinRevert I am using this configuration for a long time never faced the error. But recently I have changed my processor and then it happen

Comment: @mSapps Mmmmm...hard to tell but yes, a hardware issue could be the culprit. Maybe not the new CPU but a memory fault which was not revealed in combination with the previous CPU. I'll suggest a memcheck (using your Ubuntu start disk) and if nothing is revealed there I'll stand for a totally new Ubuntu/JRE install.

Comment: @MartinRevert it was a hardware issue, after changing ram app us working fine

Comment: Glad you solved it @mSapps