# How to enable core dump in my Java on Mac OS X?

Tags: java, macos, coredump

Honestly, I'm new to using Mac OS X El Capitan, I tried to create some Java programs and run them using Eclipse Neon. But I got this error :

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fff9c23616f, pid=810, tid=0x0000000000000a0b
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_111-b14) (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.111-b14 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libobjc.A.dylib+0x916f]  objc_release+0x1f
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/febryfairuz/Documents/workspace/FaceDetection/hs_err_pid810.log
pause dipencet
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

But when I tried running it in Windows, the program was fine.
I tried to follow this instruction :

1. [How to enable core dump in my Linux C++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919378/how-to-enable-core-dump-in-my-linux-c-program)
2. [Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982396/failed-to-write-core-dump-core-dumps-have-been-disabled)

I tried typing `ulimit -c unlimited` in the terminal but the program still got the same error. Could anyone help me how to fix this?

[image]