# Error: Starting up Eclipse with SuiteScript IDE

Tags: eclipse, netsuite, suitecloud

I just integrated SuiteCloud IDE in Eclipse as per the documentation mentioned [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/netsuitecs_gs/NSIDE/NSIDE.pdf).

After successful installation, it asked to restart Eclipse. But after restarting, the application exits with the following error log

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fbdf00de85c, pid=7431, 
   tid=0x00007fbe9ef95700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_171-b11) (build 
  1.8.0_171-8u171-b11-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-b11)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.171-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 
  compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0+0x4e85c]  gdk_display_open+0x5c
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable 
  core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

......
......

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sun.awt.X11.XDesktopPeer.init()Z+0
j  sun.awt.X11.XDesktopPeer.initWithLock()V+9
j  sun.awt.X11.XDesktopPeer.isDesktopSupported()Z+0
j  sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.isDesktopSupported()Z+0
j  java.awt.Desktop.isDesktopSupported()Z+15
j  com.netsuite.ide.eclipse.app.SourceProvider.getJavaDesktopState()Ljava/lang/String;+0
j  com.netsuite.ide.eclipse.app.SourceProvider.getCurrentState()Ljava/util/Map;+44
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationService.addSourceProvider(Lorg/eclipse/ui/ISourceProvider;)V+20

.....
.....

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00007fbe995aa000 JavaThread "process reaper" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7481, stack(0x00007fbe2875e000,0x00007fbe28797000)]
  0x00007fbe995a2800 JavaThread "AWT-XAWT" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7479, stack(0x00007fbdf0ba0000,0x00007fbdf0ca1000)]
  0x00007fbe99590800 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7478, stack(0x00007fbdf0ca1000,0x00007fbdf0da2000)]
  0x00007fbe98816000 JavaThread "H2 Log Writer NETSUITE" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7477, stack(0x00007fbdf191e000,0x00007fbdf1a1f000)]
  0x00007fbe9894a000 JavaThread "H2 File Lock Watchdog /home/.../workspace/.metadata/.plugins/com.netsuite.ide.eclipse.app/netsuite.lock.db" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7476, stack(0x00007fbdf1c1f000,0x00007fbdf1d20000)]
```

My OS is Ubuntu 18.04. I am using Eclipse 4.5.2 and SuiteCloud 18_1

Comment: Did you recently update to SuiteCloud 18_1?

Comment: Actually, this is my first setup.

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to SuiteCloud 18_1 and TLS 1.2 support in Eclipse, although in Windows, you only get an error when trying to connect a NetSuite account.

Go to your eclipse.ini file in your user installation directory and add the following to the bottom of the file: "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2"

Also, make sure your update site is set to: http://system.netsuite.com/download/ide/update_18_1.

**Update 2018-07-04:**

Part of your error says:

> Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable 
>     core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

Perhaps firstly make sure that your machine and OS match all the installation requirements mentioned in the NetSuite setup document.

I believe Java runs in a VM on Linux. Have a look at the top answer in this post: [Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982396/failed-to-write-core-dump-core-dumps-have-been-disabled)

Comment: Since Eclipse doesn't even want to run, perhaps something went wrong with the Suitecloud install taht corrupted Eclipse. I would reinstall Eclipse and try adding the update site again. I'm adding an update to my answer too.